# Including OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h not working when compiling for Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I try to integrate google test to my iOS project. As advised by google, i created a Mac target and added my source files to this target. I am unable to compile the target, and receive a not found error for the following include:

```
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
```

I made sure that the OpenGL framework is added to the target.
The code compiles without error for the iOS target.

Do i need to add something else to the Mac target?

Answer (score 1):

OS X doesn't support OpenGL ES.